# discord.js - Bot sending messages twice

Tags: discord.js

My discord bot keeps sending messages twice, as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh4Kn.png).

Here's the simplified code for `index.js`:

```js
const { prefix, token, giphyToken } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs')
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

var GphApiClient = require('giphy-js-sdk-core')
giphy = GphApiClient(giphyToken)

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');

});


for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
        client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
})
client.login(token);
```

I even tried changing the token multiple times and I killed the terminal to get rid of multiple instances, but nothing prevailed.
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't see anything in this code indicating it should run twice.  There are two possibilities.

1. The fault is in the executed command code.
2. You accidentally ran the program twice and both instances are responding.

Option 2 is a bit tricky.  If you have a test and a production environment, make sure they are using different client tokens.  It's possible to have two scripts logged in as the same bot if they both use the same token (which is why you NEVER share your token!)

Comment: I don't know if option 2 is correct. I should note that it sends messages twice and then doesn't. I don't know why it happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out what was happening here, it was an issue with pm2.

Long story short, don't run pm2 and `node .` at the same time, that was what caused this issue.

Answer (score 6):

This has happened to me before. How I fixed it is to regenerate the discord token. There was 2 things happening in the background.

Comment: This wasn't OP's problem, but it was mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If this still happens after to regenerating the token, try using `client.destroy()` on the code, or killing the exiting process by using `cmd+Z` in your terminal.

If it is *still* happening after that, just restart your computer. The most likely issue is that your application has runs twice behind.

[image: here is my terminal log]

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I did was close and re-open the text editor.